# exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hsqldb/Server

Tags: jasper-reports

I am totally new to Jasper report.

While I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://jasperforge.org/website/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/ir_design_a_report.html?header=project&target=ireport), I am stuck on this error.

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hsqldb/Server
```

I put the unzipped folder under `C:` and try to run it from command prompt.

I am running on `jdk 1.5` and just start to learn jasper report.

Any setting requirements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry .. my bad.. the one I downloaded jar file is different from jar name the tutorial mentioned. :) just need to change the jar name.

Comment: Just a heads up, you can mark your own answer as the accepted answer by clicking the check mark to the left of your answer.